# Special character in Scala symbol

Tags: scala

I like to use "-" in a Scala symbol but it doesn't appear possible, e.g.,

```
scala> val foobar = 'foo-bar
<console>:7: error: value - is not a member of Symbol
```

Ideas? Besides using "_" instead of "-".

Comment: It's a plain id, so `'foo_-`. For that matter, `'-`. I know, not what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val foobar = Symbol("foo-bar")
```